# Magento 2 : How to get selected record from ui form fieldset listing grid in controller?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, php-7, ui-grid

I have created one UI form with UI grid. When I get params in controller I can not get selected row of UI grid. How to do that?

Here is my UI Component layout file.

```
<fieldset name="other_field">    
    <field name="1">
    </field>
    <field name="2">
    </field>
    <field name="3">
    </field>
</fieldset>
<fieldset name="slider_config">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
             <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
             <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
             <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add Slides to Slider</item>
             <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">21</item>
                    </item>
        </argument>
        <insertListing>
             <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="autoRender" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                   <item name="ns" xsi:type="string">vendor_module_slide_listing</item>
                   </item>
             </argument>
        </insertListing>
</fieldset>
```

In above code i need selected rows of insertListing in controller file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that, create phtml file in adminhtml for add selected product ids in hidden field and pass into js.

Follow this below steps :

**1) Create this phtml file in your adminhtml templates**

> /app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/templates/slides.phtml

```
<?php
$blockGrid = $block->getBlockGrid();
$gridJsObjectName = $blockGrid->getJsObjectName();

?>
<?= $block->getGridHtml() ?>
<input type="hidden" name="slides" data-form-part="product_form" id="slides" value=""  />
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "SIT_ProductFaqNew/js/assign-faq": {
                "selectedProducts":  <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductsJson() ?>,
                "gridJsObjectName": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ '"' . $gridJsObjectName . '"' ?: '{}' ?>
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<script>
    require('mage/apply/main').apply();
</script>
```

**2) Add code of getProductsJson() function in block file of product grid.**

> /app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/AssignSlides.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Template;

class AssignSlides extends Template {
    /**
     * Block template
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_template = 'assign_slides.phtml';

    protected $yourCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder,
        \Vendor\Module\Model\SlidesFactory $yourCollectionFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->registry = $registry;
        $this->jsonEncoder = $jsonEncoder;
        $this->yourCollectionFactory = $yourCollectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getProductsJson() {

        $entity_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('entity_id');

        $yourCollectionFactory = $this->yourCollectionFactory->create()->load($entity_id);

        if (isset($yourCollectionFactory)) {
            $result = $yourCollectionFactory['slides'];
            $result = explode(',', $result);
            return $this->jsonEncoder->encode($result);
        }
        return '{}';
    }
}
```

**3) Assign json value in your hidden field in this js file :**

> /app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/web/js/assign-products.js

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/* global $, $H */

define([
    'mage/adminhtml/grid'
], function () {
    'use strict';

    return function (config) {
        var selectedProducts = config.selectedProducts,
            categoryProducts = $H(selectedProducts),
            gridJsObject = window[config.gridJsObjectName],
            tabIndex = 1000;
        /**
         * Show selected product when edit form in associated product grid
         */
        $('slides').value = Object.toJSON(categoryProducts); // add your hidden field id
        /**
         * Register Category Product
         *
         * @param {Object} grid
         * @param {Object} element
         * @param {Boolean} checked
         */
        function registerCategoryProduct(grid, element, checked) {
            if (checked) {
                if (element.positionElement) {
                    element.positionElement.disabled = false;
                    categoryProducts.set(element.value, element.positionElement.value);
                }
            } else {
                if (element.positionElement) {
                    element.positionElement.disabled = true;
                }
                categoryProducts.unset(element.value);
            }
            $('slides').value = Object.toJSON(categoryProducts); // add your hidden field id
            grid.reloadParams = {
                'selected_products[]': categoryProducts.keys()
            };
        }

        /**
         * Click on product row
         *
         * @param {Object} grid
         * @param {String} event
         */
        function categoryProductRowClick(grid, event) {
            var trElement = Event.findElement(event, 'tr'),
                isInput = Event.element(event).tagName === 'INPUT',
                checked = false,
                checkbox = null;

            if (trElement) {
                checkbox = Element.getElementsBySelector(trElement, 'input');

                if (checkbox[0]) {
                    checked = isInput ? checkbox[0].checked : !checkbox[0].checked;
                    gridJsObject.setCheckboxChecked(checkbox[0], checked);
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Change product position
         *
         * @param {String} event
         */
        function positionChange(event) {
            var element = Event.element(event);

            if (element && element.checkboxElement && element.checkboxElement.checked) {
                categoryProducts.set(element.checkboxElement.value, element.value);
                $('slides').value = Object.toJSON(categoryProducts); // add your hidden field id
            }
        }

        /**
         * Initialize category product row
         *
         * @param {Object} grid
         * @param {String} row
         */
        function categoryProductRowInit(grid, row) {
            var checkbox = $(row).getElementsByClassName('checkbox')[0],
                position = $(row).getElementsByClassName('input-text')[0];

            if (checkbox && position) {
                checkbox.positionElement = position;
                position.checkboxElement = checkbox;
                position.disabled = !checkbox.checked;
                position.tabIndex = tabIndex++;
                Event.observe(position, 'keyup', positionChange);
            }
        }

        gridJsObject.rowClickCallback = categoryProductRowClick;
        gridJsObject.initRowCallback = categoryProductRowInit;
        gridJsObject.checkboxCheckCallback = registerCategoryProduct;

        if (gridJsObject.rows) {
            gridJsObject.rows.each(function (row) {
                categoryProductRowInit(gridJsObject, row);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: I am getting this error "Call to a member function getJsObjectName() on null" because it is not defined in block anywhere